# How to access to a dictionary key using a string that contain partial string of the key?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, tuples

If I have a key like this: `ex_key = ('a','z')`

How can I add value to the dictionary key that contains either character of ex_key above?

For example, using the key above, I'm trying to append the value to the key `('a',)` in the dictionary. Since key `('a',)` contains partial character of `ex_key`. And `('a','b')` key does not count, since the `ex_key` is `('a','z')`.

```
d = {('a', 'b'): {('a', 'b', 'c')}, ('a', 'b', 'c'): {('a', 'b', 'c')}, ('a',): {('u', 'm', 'c')}}**
```

Expected:

```
{('a', 'b'): {('a', 'b', 'c')}, ('a', 'b', 'c'): {('a', 'b', 'c')}, **('a',): {('a','z'), ('u', 'm', 'c')}}**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if all(i in ex_key for i in k):
        d[k] = v.union({ex_key})
```

Comment: That condition does not respect position. `all(a == b for a,b in zip(k, ex_key))`. Now if it supposed to match the longest prefix, one would be better off with a loop over the prefixes of ex_key and probe the dictionary in descending length.

Comment: @DanD. Right. But does OP care about position matching?

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
ex_key = ('a','z')
d = {('a', 'b'): {('a', 'b', 'c')}, ('a', 'b', 'c'): {('a', 'b', 'c')}, ('a',): {('u', 'm', 'c')}}

if ex_key in d:
    d[ex_key].add(ex_key)
else:
    for k in ex_key:
        if (k,) in d:
            d[(k,)].add(ex_key)
print(d)
```